# How do I create a popup as the same one on the site https://www.sublimotionibiza.com/es/main.html, when you click the contact button

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I would like to create the same popup that happens, when you click the contact button from the site: https://www.sublimotionibiza.com/es/main.html.
If somebody can just show me where I have gone wrong with the following code I have tried to create this slow moving opening popup. Here is the code, I tried.

```js
document.querySelector("#open-popup").addEventListener("click",function(){
  document.querySelector(".popup").classList.add("active");
});

document.querySelector(".popup .popup-container .popup-close").addEventListener("click",function(){
  document.querySelector(".popup").classList.remove("active");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin:0px;
}
.popup {
  position:fixed;
  top:-100vh;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  transition:top 0ms ease-in-out 900ms;
}
.popup.active {
  transition:top 0ms ease-in-out;
  top:0vh;
}
.popup .popup-container {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1.2);
  width:400px;
  padding:30px 20px 20px;
  background:#eee;
  opacity:0.5;
  transition:all 900ms ease-in-out;
}
.popup.active .popup-container {
  opacity:1;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);
}
.popup .popup-container .popup-close {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:#111;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px;
  color:#eee;
  border-radius:50%;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:600;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.popup .popup-container h1 {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
  font-family:"Raleway";
  color:#222;
}
.popup .popup-container p {
  margin-top:10px;
  font-size:15px;
  font-family:"Raleway";
  color:#555;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup-container">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>information: email: spencerhalstead27@gmail.com tel: 073 814 8752</p>
    <div class="popup-close">&times;</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="open-popup">Open Popup</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make it bigger, it's size should be 0 at the beginning, and then fixed size number

Comment: No, I want my popup to have the same opening effect as the one on that website does.

Comment: that's it... instead transform: translate, try to manipulate height from 0 to necessary height